# Excel Help - trying to use an helper column to filter/match a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use helper cells in column a to see if there is match to a single cell.

So in the img, I want to use all keywords in column a to see if there is a match to c3, c4, c5... etc.

I would then use the new list filtered cells to match to the helper column in step 4.

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: So, if a cell in Column C has a word that exists in Column A, you want to return that Column C reference/text?  So if `C5` was `a/c unit`, you'd like `a/c unit` to be outputted in column I?  I think I'm missing something regarding your Column G.

Comment: Column I would ideally output a true or false outcome. So initially column a would contain ac, remodel, and other keywords. If c5 matches any of the keywords in column a. I would like an output of match or no match in column I

Comment: True or False ...meaning what? If what's true/false?

Comment: Meaning a if there cell c5 matches any values in column a

Comment: Does the text in column C need to match the info in column A exactly? Or can partial matches apply.  For example, if you have "abc" in cell `C4`, what is the expected result for cells in Column A, `abc`, `abcdef`, `a abc a`.  `True/False/False`?

Comment: It doesn't need to match exactly. So if C4 (abcd),  matches any values in column a (a, b, ced, abe) then the output should be match in cell i4. So if c5 is (xzjk) then the value in i5 would be no match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: POC]

based on the above layout, and what my understanding on the question and comments you would be looking for the results in column G

Place the following formula in G3 and copy down.  Adjust cell reference ranges as required to suit your data.

```
=IF(ISERR(AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH($A$3:$A$7,C3),1)),"Not Found",C3)
```